# What is the best way to implement Django 3 Modal forms?

Tags: python, jquery, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I appreciate it if somebody gives the main idea of how to handle submission/retrieval form implementation in Bootstrap modals. I saw many examples on google but it is still ambiguous for me. Why it is required to have a separate Html file for modal-forms template? Where SQL commands will be written? What is the flow in submission/retrieval forms (I mean steps)? What is the best practice to implement these kind of forms? I'm fairly new to Django, please be nice and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No need for separate file for modal-form. Here MVT structure following, whenever forms are used. Easy interaction to template. Moreover if you go through Django documentation, you will get to know easily. 
Submission - mention the form action url. It will call that and check the django forms

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind,then you new in django first go through the following link read all pages is simple after done this site, then you go on django docs it my advice
you learn flow of form submission of model

[simple is better then complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/)

then go on docs and see